# How to create PDF from HTML in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, pdf

I am facing issue creating PDF file from HTML text stored in a variable.
I have tried **zendpdf** but it directly prints tags also.

Here's my code:

```
$pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
$page = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$pdf->pages[] = $page;
$page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 20);
$page->drawText('<h1>hello</h1>', 100, 510);
$pdfData = $pdf->render();
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=result.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/x-pdf");
echo $pdfData;
```

Comment: Try this https://github.com/weprovide/magento2-module-dompdf

Comment: thanks for response bt it have some errors

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cellmap() on null in /var/www/html/m21/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/FrameReflower/TableCell.php:37\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/m21/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/FrameDecorator

Comment: putting this `'<h1>hello</h1>'` into a variable, like this `$text = '<h1>hello</h1>'` and from there you can use the variable, `$page->drawText($text, 100, 510);`

Comment: @magefms it prints tags also

Comment: Im not sure what ur asking is possible with ZendPDF but there is an alternative thankfully. check this link out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563370/create-a-pdf-with-tcpdf-in-magento think this would help

Comment: @DavaGordon done thanks..